# How to find average of a column in a txt file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Practicing some Python and am trying to solve an a problem that asks to get the average age of students in a text file. Ex. of the .txt file shown below.

```
   Sam, 23
   Jack 20
   Tara 19
   Stacy 22
```

Normally I would re-trace my steps with an error message, but my output is just a 0. I'm not sure if using read instead of readlines is correct either.

```
def sumNums():
    infile = open('student_age.txt', 'r')
    fileContents = infile.read()
    infile.close

    count= 0

    for lines in fileContents.split(','):
        if lines.isdigit():
            count += lines

    print(sum(count) / len(lines))
```

Actual output should be 21 since 84/4=21 but I am getting 0

Comment: first of all, `infile.close` does nothing. If you want to close the file, you have to call it `infile.close()` . Second, in your sample, you only have one comma `,`, such that the splits would fail for most lines. Third, you have lots of `\n` hidden in your `fileContents`, such that `split(',')` would yield something like `['Sam', ' 23\nJack','20']` etc. Then, `isdigit()` would always be `False` and the `count+=lines` would never be reached. You might want to use `readlines` instead of `read` and split by `, ` (with an extra space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start simpler. Start out by simply writing code that will iterate over the lines of a comma-separated file like this and print out the second value (the number) of each line.

```py
with open('path/to/file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        field1, field2 = line.split(',')
        print(field2)
```

Then you can start thinking about how to handle saving those values in memory and averaging them.

```py
with open('path/to/file.csv') as f:
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        field1, field2 = line.split(',')
        total += int(field2)
        count += 1

result = total / count
```

and *then* you can look at refactoring this to make use of the stdlib `csv` module.

```py
import csv

with open('path/to/file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    numbers = [int(num) for _, num in reader]
    total, count = sum(numbers), len(numbers)

result = total / count
```

Comment: @jackrabbit file extensions are always arbitrary (in modern computing). As long as the underlying data is formatted the same, it doesn't matter if it's a `file.csv` or a `file.txt` or a `file.zip` or a `file.exe`.

Comment: This has been a ton of help, thank you Adam! I'm trying to learn the fundamentals of python first before I dive into modules like csv, but I know how powerful they are and it's too tempting to use them!

Comment: @jackrabbit great! I think learning from first principles is important, but don't forget that you'll never see actual code that looks like this, and if you write code that looks like this it'll be rejected in review (or worse: NOT rejected in review and become tech debt that slowly hurts maintainability). There's a sharp contrast between the kind of code you write to understand a concept and the kind of code you write once you _do_ understand that concept, and never the twain shall meet.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
int(float("age"))
```

This should convert string into numerical values, from which you can easily take average by

```
sum("age")/len("age")
```

Comment: why `int(float(...))`? Why not just `int(...)`?

Comment: oh, it might also works, I never tried that, I usually work with floats, so I just extend this by int()

Comment: You should try and get away from working with floats if possible. They're a silly data structure :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sumNums():
    with open('student_age.txt', 'r') as f:
        count = i = 0
        for line in f:
            name, number = line.split(',')
            if number.strip().isdigit():
                count += int(number)
            i += 1

        print(count / i)

sumNums()
```

Answer (score -1):

Your are processing your file incorrectly. `infile.read()` returns all lines in the file. So you should firstly split it by `'\n'` symbols and then by ',':

```
for line in fileContents.split('\n'):
    for element in line.split(','):
        ...
```

But there is better solution...

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org)!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('student_age.txt', headers=None)
df[1].mean()  # If you have more than 2 columns, 1 can be replaced by the actual column
```

Three lines of code and you are the king.

Comment: using pandas here is like using a nuclear warhead to start a campfire. Also pointing out `fileContents = infile.read(); for line in fileContents.split('\n')` seems silly when there's `fileLines = infile.readlines()` that does all that for you.

Comment: A nuclear warhead that is not as fragile as manual CSV reading (try to add another column in the file and your solution will be broken). Moreover, it allows the OP to manipulate the data far better than `csv` module.

Comment: No one is arguing that the nuclear warhead isn't well-engineered, just that it's over-engineered for this task. This is pretty clearly a question asked by a beginner who's having trouble with a tutorial. "Oh, throw pandas at it" is not a helpful recommendation if someone is trying to learn Python.

Comment: (and notably: your solution is broken too if you add a preceding column)